# How to use CameraComponent.setBounds() in Flutter Flame?

Tags: flutter, camera, bounds, flame

I have a world and a player. My camera follows the player. The player can't go out the worlds bounds I had created, but camera can see what is behind the world borders(black screen).

I tried to add CameraComponent.setBounds(...) as mentioned in documentation. setBounds() function asks for bounds of type Shape?. What I have to pass here? Before flame update I used "worldBounds: Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, _background.size.x, _background.size.y)" in camera.followComponent, but it got deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is yet to be fully implemented in the new camera system (see https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/issues/2601).

Currently the only workaround is to calculate the bounds to be smaller than where the player can move, for example, if your world is based around (0, 0):

```dart
import 'package:flame/experimental.dart'; // Gives you the Rectangle
...

class MyGame extends FlameGame {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    final halfViewportSize = camera.viewport.size / 2;
    final worldSize = 1500; // Size from the center in each direction.
    cameraComponent.setBounds(
      Rectangle.fromCenter(
        center: Vector2.zero(),
        size: Vector2.all(worldSize) - halfViewportSize,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```